# Элемент поверх родителя

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли элемент сделать поверх родителя, чтобы на него не воздействовал `padding` родителя?

`z-nindex` не помогает

```css
.c1 {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center
}

.c2 {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы на всю высоту растянуть хотите? Поставьте отрицательный margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то вот :

```
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    Text
  </div>
</div>


.c1 {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 18px;
}

.c2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
```